# Unable to run gradle command inside Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to run Gradle in Jenkins but when it runs, it exits with the following error

```
+ gradle war --offline 
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, 
TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried to change the JDWP port like this but nothing changed.

```
gradle war --offline -Pjvmargs--Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5007
```

but when I run Gradle manually in the build path, everything goes fine.

any helps?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Gradle is running in debug mode.
Two instance of gradle cannot be run in debug mode. You can try something like,org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8011 ,server=y,suspend=n

Or change the port as JPDA_ADDRESS.

Comment: But I only run a single instance of Gradle!